# xslt-replace namespace uri alone

Tags: xml, namespaces, xslt-1.0

In my xml the namespace http://abc.com/source/error, should be replaced by http://abc.com/error/i1. I have to use xslt1.0, and it is very much challenging to replace the uri part alone. All other should be as is to the output. In case this namespace is not present, the input xml should be passed as is to output.

My input xml

```
<a xmlns:hj="http://abc.com/source/error">
<hj:b>sam</hj:b>
</a>
```

expected output

```
<a xmlns:hj="http://abc.com/source/error/i1">
<hj:b>sam</hj:b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT will do the job. But be aware it only works if the namespace prefix of the input XML is equal to `hj:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:hjold="http://abc.com/source/error" xmlns:hj="http://abc.com/source/error/i1" exclude-result-prefixes="hjold">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[namespace-uri-for-prefix('hj', /*) != '']">
        <a xmlns:hj="http://abc.com/source/error/i1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="hjold:*" >
        <xsl:element name="hj:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" >
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To use in XSLT 1.0 and the namespace does not matter in the output even if there was no namespace declared, change:

```
 <xsl:template match="a[namespace-uri-for-prefix('hj', /*) != '']">
```

to

```
 <xsl:template match="a">
```

Comment: Thanks. The namespace prefix should not matter, for the xslt. Even the xml,<a xmlns="http://abc.com/source/error">
<b>sam</b>
</a> should be working..also the xslt version is 1.0

Comment: Excuse me, but if you want to use it in XSLT 1.0 and the namespace does not matter if it is in result or not, change `<xsl:template match="a[namespace-uri-for-prefix('hj', /*) != '']">` to `<xsl:template match="a">`

Comment: mark, the input xml can be anything. that is elements can be of any number. Only the namespace should be replaced.